# What is the most reliable computer case fan you can buy?

Tags: case

I am trying to buy the **most reliable** case fan known to man. The Fans noise level can be as loud as it wants.  The fan has to have **good enough airflow**.  The fan has to **last a long time**.  Those are really the only requirements.  As far as size.. probably the most common sizes whatever that happens to be.  Size is not really important to me.  But if I was forced to pick a size, I would have to pick the most common as of right now.  Which seems to be:  120mm, 140mm, and 80mm seem to be the most common types as of right now.

A good example, and I don't want people to dwell on this very much, is enterprise.  What type of fans does enterprise use?  I know IBM sometimes uses a company called Delta.

Comment: Note: Enterprise kit would not necessarily always last longer, and rack-based systems differ from traditional server chassis and finally they usually do not consider noise a factor. So apart from wanting a long lasting fan, what other factors/criteria do we need to consider?

Comment: As written, this question is outside the scope of this site. Instead of asking what bearing type is the most reliable, ask for the most reliable fan instead. Please [edit] your question to include the size and any other requirements/wants that you may have.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments/feedback, I appreciate it.

Comment: **Don't** just re-ask your question because it was closed. You've already been given advice here on how to get this one reopened. I've merged your re-asked duplicate into this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the consumer side I would recommend a [Noctua industrial series](https://noctua.at/en/products/fan/industrial) fan. I can't say much about the enterprise products as I am not familiar with them.